# How can you run http.server without a port and simply on localhost?

Tags: python-3.x, localhost, port, httpserver

I usually start `http.server` by typing
`python3 -m http.server port` and I can access the server by going to `localhost:port`

My goal is to access the srver by simply typing `localhost`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is always port... the default is 80, so just run it on 80 and you'll reach it by just localhost.

Comment: I typed `python3 -m http.server 80` and got `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`

Comment: Solved it by adding `sudo` in front. Thank you for your help!